# Pandas apply function to dataframe index series within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to create a function that uses columns of a dataframe as input.  Part of this input will be a series.

So it would function like the below

```
def myFunc(input1, input2, s_input):
    for s in s_input['c':'d'].index:
       print s + str(s_input[s]) +str(input1)
    for s in s_input['e':].index:
        print s + str(s_input[s]) +str(input2)

s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':4,'c':7,'d':11,'e':15,'f':22})   

input1=' input1'
input2 =' input2'

myFunc(input1,input2,s) 

c7 input1
d11 input1
e15 input2
f22 input2
```

I want to apply this to a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9],'d':[11,12,13], 'e':[11,23,33], 'f':[75,44,55]})    

df.apply(lambda x: myFunc(df.a,df.b, df.loc[x.index,'c':]))
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply your function row-wise here, use `axis = 1` on the `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: myFunc(x.a, x.b, x.loc['c':]), axis=1)

# gets printed...
c71
d111
e114
f754
c82
d122
e235
f445
c93
d133
e336
f556
```

However, you usually employ `apply` to return values. At the moment, your function does not return anything.

Comment: I knew I was close.  Now I think I understand lambda, don't know why I didn't before.